# Play Framework + Spring, dependency injection to Global object

Tags: spring, playframework

I use Play Framework + Spring Data JPA from this example:

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa

I have models, repositories and now I want to initialize my DB on start up. I inject repositories to my Global.java file using `@Autowired`, but they equals to `null` on run time. It's because Spring don't try to inject dependencies to Global.java, because Global.java don't have even package name, so I can't tell Spring to scan his package!

With controllers Spring DI works well, but how to use it in Global.java? How to initialize database using repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change package of `Global.java` in `application.conf` by setting property `application.global`.

Other way can be to fetch dependency explicitly calling

```
context.getBean(YourBeanClass)
```

in `Global.java` instead of **autowiring** it, as you have context available in `Global`.

Comment: Explicit calling ```context.getBean()``` is working for me. Autowiring still is not working, but probably it's because Global object is not managed by Spring and Play Framework creates it. Not sure, if possible to use ```@Autowired``` in Global object and maybe it's bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, I gave a try as well. @Autowired does't work in global. Probably because Spring doesn't recognize it as a component.

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly create a bean by defining it in your context xml
`<bean id="global" class="Global"></bean>`

Also, having classes in default packages is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't have any classes in default package. There is only Global class. Also I tried combine xml configurations from here https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo and annotation based configuration from here https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa but failed. I can choose only one. So I don't have context.xml file. Is there any examples, how to combine them?

Comment: Okay, I combined that configurations using answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049778/how-to-configure-spring-data-jpa-using-xml But when I define bean, nothing changes, fields still equals to ```null```. I also tried to add setter for ```@Autowired``` field and add parameter to bean, but it didn't work.