# I have a javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

## The exception that i have

```
  javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.persist(Unknown Source)
        com.cnp.incident.dao.FluxEntreesDAO.ajouterFlux(FluxEntreesDAO.java:37)
        com.cnp.incident.services.ServiceFluxEntrees.ajouterFlux(ServiceFluxEntrees.java:33)
        com.cnp.incident.controller.CreationManuelleFluxEntreesSorties.creer(CreationManuelleFluxEntreesSorties.java:64)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

## root-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cnp.incident"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>       
<!-- Unite de persistence -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cnp.incident"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
      <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>
        <!-- A utiliser pour faciliter le debug -->
        <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
        <!-- activation cache d'entités et de query -->
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>   
    <!-- on référence la datasource "lazy" -->
  </bean>
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

## My DAO

```
package com.cnp.incident.dao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.cnp.incident.entite.FluxEntrees;
@Repository
public class FluxEntreesDAO implements IfluxEntreesDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    //implémentation de la methode listeFlux de la DAO
    public List<FluxEntrees> listeFlux() {
        final CriteriaBuilder lCriteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<FluxEntrees> lCriteriaQuery = lCriteriaBuilder.createQuery(FluxEntrees.class);
        final Root<FluxEntrees> lRoot = lCriteriaQuery.from(FluxEntrees.class);
        lCriteriaQuery.select(lRoot);
        final TypedQuery<FluxEntrees> lTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(lCriteriaQuery);
        return lTypedQuery.getResultList();
    }

    //methode d'ajout de flux en base de données
    public void ajouterFlux(final FluxEntrees pFlux) {
        entityManager.persist(pFlux);

    }
}
```

## My Service

```
package com.cnp.incident.services;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.cnp.incident.dao.IfluxEntreesDAO;
import com.cnp.incident.entite.FluxEntrees;
@Service
public class ServiceFluxEntrees implements IServiceFluxEntrees{

    @Autowired
    private IfluxEntreesDAO dao;
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<FluxEntrees> listeFlux() {
        return dao.listeFlux();
    }
    @Transactional
    public void ajouterFlux(Date mois, Integer entree, Integer sorties, String type) {

        final FluxEntrees fluxEntrees = new FluxEntrees();
        fluxEntrees.setMois(mois);
        fluxEntrees.setEntrees(entree);
        fluxEntrees.setSorties(sorties);
        fluxEntrees.setType(type);

        dao.ajouterFlux(fluxEntrees);
    }
}*
```

Comment: The exception occur when i add ne w Flux with method ajouterFlux(Date mois, Integer entree, Integer sorties, String type); with line dao.ajouterFlux(fluxEntrees);

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes to your transaction manager configuration (I'll only list the parts that need to be changed):

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
...
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I got the same above exception after chaged

Comment: @MamadouBhoyeBARRY What if you remove the existing `sessionFactory` and `transactionManager` bean definitions? Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049778/how-to-configure-spring-data-jpa-using-xml) for an example.