# Spring Security Initialization throwing UnsatisfiedDependencyException on mvcContentNegotiationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement **Spring Security 5.0.0.RELEASE** in an existing **Spring MVC project**. Note that it is entirely Annotation Based.

Following is the code for my `WebAppInitializer` :

```
package com.abc.webapp.core;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.abc.webapp.config");
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcherServlet",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Following is the `WebMVCConfig` File -

```
package com.abc.webapp.config;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.webapp.controller" })
public class AppContextWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/");
    }
}
```

Now as per the [Spring Security Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) I am trying to configure like following -

```
package com.abc.webapp.config;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AppContextSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // Code for Login URL and Logout URL 
    }
}
```

And

```
package com.abc.webapp.core;

public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

When I am trying to start the server I am getting the following **stacktrace** -

```
[ERROR][2018-01-30 01:40:13 ContextLoader:351] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appContextSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:651)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
```

I am quite sure I am not missing any steps mentioned in the Srping setup. I have googled several times but of no use. I am also tried removing the `SecurityWebAppInitializer` and manually adding the filter in the `WebAppInitializer` like the following way.

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic  springSecurityFilterChain = container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

**And I am still getting the exception during startup. Any clues or solutions are highly appreciated.**

Comment: Since your full code is not available, it seems that you have autowired a dependency `mvcContentNegotiationManager` somewhere in your code. Have you?

Comment: I haven't autowired mvcContentNegotiationManager explicitly anywhere in the config classes. Any other clue you can think of?

Comment: Are you using spring boot ? if yes, what version of spring boot ?

Comment: I think, its a jar version problem of spring-web. Have you tried to analyse your pom.xml with eclipse. Open you pom.xml with eclipe and go to dependency hierarchy and search for the version of spiring-web. There should be one version.

Comment: You'd better paste pom.xml and other config files

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568047/4763309 looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to an incompatibility of your spring-web-X.X.X.RELEASE.jar , Spring Data Commons jar. Please check spring jar versions using following command

```
mvn dependency:tree.
```